# How to pass value to Crystal Report parameters in JSP?

Tags: jsp, crystal-reports

Could any one tell me how to pass value to Crystal Report parameters in JSP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to search and try to implement some tutorials available.

Here are some links : [Example 1](http://danfolkes.com/2008/02/07/jsp-crystal-reports/)

http://ftp1.businessobjects.com/outgoing/Products/DevZone/CrystalCaseStudy.pdf

Personally, I suggest to use Jasper Reports with JSP.